# Nested Git repositories: `commit` in sub-repository without affecting parent

Tags: git, git-commit

Edit: Looks like it works I do not know why it did not.

I wrote an application that interact with git repositories.

In order to have correct integration tests I generate a git repository from dummy sources.

The issue is that during those test I use `commit` and this affects the base repository.

How can I `commit` in sub-repository without `commit`ing to parent one ?

This is a small reproduction of my issue:

```bash
$ mkdir /tmp/test-git
$ git -C /tmp/test-git init
$ mkdir /tmp/test-git/sub-git
$ git -C /tmp/test-git/sub-git init
$ touch /tmp/test-git/sub-git/file.txt
$ git -C /tmp/test-git/sub-git add .
$ git -C /tmp/test-git/sub-git commit --message "Initial commit"
$ git -C /tmp/test-git/sub-git log --oneline
2501e5f (HEAD -> main) test
$ git -C /tmp/test-git log --oneline
2501e5f (HEAD -> main) test # Expected: fatal: your current branch 'main' does not have any commits yet
```

I did check [`commit` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) and cannot seem to be able to find a specific flag to add that would avoid the commit in the parent repository.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I get the expected error message with the last command.

Comment: These aren't really nested repositories; neither repository is aware of the other. You just have two repositories. The fact that one is stored in a subdirectory of a working directory of the other isn't something Git knows or cares about.